# If $A,B$ symmetric positive semidefinite, show tr$(AB) \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Supposing $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$) of dimension $n$, and $A,B$ are symmetric positive definite linear mappings from $V$ to $V$, how can I show that in any orthonormal basis $\mathrm{tr}(AB) \geq 0$?

I noticed that since they are symmetric we have that 
$$\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}B_{ji} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}B_{ij}$$ which is the sum of the elements of the element-wise product of $A,B$. I don't know if this is helpful.

Comment: I think you may as well assume $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and that $A$ and $B$ are matrices. Symmetric positive-definite linear maps don't make much sense except in the presence of a chosen isomorphism $V \cong V^*$.

Comment: If this is homework, can you assume the spectral theorem? That is, can you assume the nice properties that hold about matrices' eigenvalues when they are symmetric & positive definite?

Comment: Yes we may assume $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and yes you may use the spectral theorem. But remember the result must hold for all orthonormal bases, not just the one where $A$ is diagonal.\

Comment: See also: [Product of positive-definite matrices has positive trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/310580)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this may be homework, I will only give hints.

1. Without loss of generality you may assume that $V=R^n$.
2. Trace is independent of the basis you use. Thus it suffices to 
   show this in the basis where $A$ is diagonal.
3. A positive semi-definite matrix has nonnegative diagonal. Why?
4. Putting 1-3 together, one needs to show that the $tr(AB)\geq 0$ where $A$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix and $B$ has nonnegative diagonal.

Answer (score 15):

As others have remarked, you might as well suppose that $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices. We may write $A = X^{t}X$ and $B = Y^{t}Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are $n \times n$ real matrices. Then ${\rm tr}(AB) = {\rm tr}(X^{t}X Y^{t}Y)$ = ${\rm tr}((YX^{t})(XY^{t})).$ The latter matrix has the form ${\rm tr}(UU^{t})$ for a real $n \times n$ matrix $U$, and such a trace is always non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another derivation (7 years later):

Let $A,B\succeq0$. Then the eigendecomposition of symmetric $B$ gives $B=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}[AB]&=\operatorname{Tr}[A\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \operatorname{Tr}[Av_i v_i^T]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{\lambda_i}_{\geq0} \underbrace{v_i^TAv_i}_{\geq0} \\
&\geq 0
\end{align}$$

where the last equality is from the cyclic property of the trace.

Feel free to ask for any clarifications neeeded.

**Edit: Here's the explanation of the eigendecomposition.**

In matrix form, the eigen-equation is: $BV=V\Lambda$, where $V$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors $\{v_i\}$ of $B$, and where $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $B$ along the diagonal. Because $B$ is symmetric, these $V$ matrices are orthogonal, meaning their columns are orthonormal, so $VV^T=V^TV=I_n$. We can then re-write the matrix equation: $BVV^T=B=V\Lambda V^T$.

$$\begin{align}
\rightarrow B &=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & \cdots & v_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \lambda_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1^T\\
\vdots\\
v_n^T
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & \cdots & v_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1v_1^T\\
\vdots\\
\lambda_nv_n^T
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T
\end{align}$$

where this is a sum of outer products of the eigenvectors. Note that I wrote my matrices above as vector with elements that are vectors. This shorthand is valid and very convenient, but feel free to write it out and check me!