# Product of positive-definite matrices has positive trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

In his paper "On the existence of a connection with curvature zero", Milnor makes the following claim.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive-definite $n \times n$ matrices.  Then the trace of $X Y$ is positive.  I can't figure out how to prove this.  Can someone help me?

Comment: See also: [If $A,B$ symmetric positive semidefinite, show tr$(AB) \geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113298)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $A$ be the positive definite square root of $X$ and $B$ the positive definite square root of $Y$.

You have
$$
\mbox{tr}(XY)=\mbox{tr}(AABB)=\mbox{tr}(BAAB)=\mbox{tr}((AB)^*AB)>0.
$$

Indeed, the latter is the sum of all $c_{i,j}^2$ where $c_{i,j}=(AB)_{i,j}$.

So it is nonnegative.

And if it were zero, this would imply $AB=0$ hence $A=B=0$ since they are both invertible. Contradiction.