# How do I prove that $\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}b_{ij} \geq 0$ if $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$ are both positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, matrix-analysis

This is an exercise in [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra):

> Let $A=(a_{ij})$  and $B=(b_{ij})$
>   both be [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix) $n \times n$ (real) matrices.
>   Prove that 
>   $$
>  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij} \geq 0\,.
> $$

---

This is a known fact when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310580/product-of-positive-definite-matrices-has-positive-trace) is an analogous fact for positive definite symmetric matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: the quantity you are interested in is the trace of $AB$. Show that $AB$ is a sum pf $M_{x,z}=xx^Tzz^T$ for vectors $x,z$. Note that the trace of $M_{x,z}$ is the trace of $(x^Tz)(z^Tx)$ where the two matrix products between parentheses are $1 \times 1$ matrices, the transpose one of the other. So they are equal and the trace is the square of $x \cdot z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a related (counter)example if we remove the "symmetric" assumptions on $A$ and $B$: 
\begin{align}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \\ 
3 & 1\end{array}\right]\\
B &= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 3 \\ 
-1 & 1\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
It can be shown that $x^TAx \geq 0$ and $x^TBx \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, but 
$$ \sum_{ij} a_{ij}b_{ij} = (1)(1) + (-1)(3) + (3)(-1) + (1)(1) = -4$$

---

On the other hand, if $A, B$ are real-valued $n \times n$ matrices that satisfy $x^TAx \geq 0$ and $x^TBx \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and if $A$ is symmetric, then the situation is different: We can say $A = R^TR$ for some square matrix $R$ and so 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij}=trace(A^TB) = trace(R^TR B)= ...$$
so you can use properties of the trace to eventually prove $trace(A^TB)\geq 0$. In particular, the desired non-negativity result holds as long as *at least one* of the matrices $A, B$ is also assumed to be symmetric.